# Different background for different page

Tags: css

I was wondering if there is a way to set a different background for each page. I tried with this code you posted on a different thread, but it didn’t work:

```
section-padding.page-id-8  {
background-color: #e0e0e0;

}
```

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: Probably the best way to go about it would be to make a custom field for background color (or use the free version of ACF) and then populate that entry inline in your style in the header. That way you can a) have a fallback if none is set and b) allow ease of updating.

Comment: @BradDalton I think it's Swiss Progress. http://clientswissprogress.com/wp-content/themes/Template%20Swiss%20Progress/style.css

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible! For the default homepage, you can use this:

```
body.home {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

For a specific blog post, you can use this where 5 is its post ID:

```
body.postid-5 {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

And this is for a specific page and it's the same where 5 is the page ID:

```
body.page-id-5 {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

Comment: This solved the OP's question according to his/her answered comment, any reason for the down-vote?